# switching between html and php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to achieve a red background color for a table cell if the query yields no as an answer and red background otherwise.I'm a beginner in php and dont know how to switch between html and php code.

```
<?php  if($row1['attended']==1){ ?>
     < td style="background-color:#99ff99"><?php echo "Yes";}?>
     </td>
 <?php  else{ ?>
    <td style="background-color:#ffb3b3"><?php echo "No";}?>
    </td>
```

the error I'm getting :

> syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Comment: You need to close the `else`, here -> `<?php  else{ ?>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically there. One thing to know is that conditionals have [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) that make it look cleaner when mixing your PHP and HTML.

```
<?php if ($row1['attended'] == 1) : ?>
    <td style="background-color:#99ff99">Yes</td>
<?php  else : ?>
    <td style="background-color:#ffb3b3">No</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In modern PHP development, it is good to rely on templating such as Twig or things built into frameworks like Laravel's Blade.

Answer (score 1):

You should

```
  <?php  
      if($row1['attended']==1){  
        echo ' <td style="background-color: #99ff99"> Yes </td>'
       }
       else{ 
        echo '<td style="background-color:#ffb3b3">No</td>';
       }
  ?>
```